# What is the best compression algorithm for increasing number?

Tags: compression

We have some random number that are different each other and increase every and between 0 to 255.

For example {**3,18,54,68,90,100,150,200,240,255**}

which one algorithm is better sufficient for compressing?

Answer (score 1):

For values that are close, Delta compression (modulation) is good choice. You store first value and than you store difference to next value. In you example it will be
3,15,36,14,22,10,50,50,40,15
Note that you don't have 3 digit values, so total size in used bytes is lower
(Phone communications use this, since humans mostly use small range of frequency when talk)

Comment: I know the delta. I am looking for a better method.